# How to let nom::alt return an impl type?

Tags: rust, token, tokenize, nom

So I'm trying to tokenize a file. I just started. I implemented the parsing of a StringLiteral, and of a IntegerLiteral. I want my nom parser to return a generic impl of Token, but I'm getting the following error message

```
type mismatch resolving `<for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> Result<(&'r str, Box<IntegerLiteral>), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&'r str>>> {<IntegerLiteral as lexer::Token>::parse} as FnOnce<(&str,)>>::Output == Result<(&str, Box<StringLiteral>), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>>`
expected enum `Result<(&str, Box<StringLiteral>), _>`
   found enum `Result<(&str, Box<IntegerLiteral>), _>`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `Parser<&str, Box<StringLiteral>, nom::error::Error<&str>>` for `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> Result<(&'r str, Box<IntegerLiteral>), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&'r str>>> {<IntegerLiteral as lexer::Token>::parse}`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `nom::branch::Alt<&str, Box<StringLiteral>, nom::error::Error<&str>>` for `(for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> Result<(&'r str, Box<StringLiteral>), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&'r str>>> {<StringLiteral as lexer::Token>::parse}, for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> Result<(&'r str, Box<IntegerLiteral>), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&'r str>>> {<IntegerLiteral as lexer::Token>::parse})`
```

This is (most of) the code:

```rust
impl Lexer{
    pub fn run(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Box<impl Token>>{
        alt(
            (StringLiteral::parse, IntegerLiteral::parse)
        )(input)
    }
}

pub trait Token: std::fmt::Debug {
    fn parse(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Box<Self>> 
        where Self: Sized;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct StringLiteral {
    string: String
}

impl Token for StringLiteral {
    fn parse(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Box<Self>> {
        delimited(char('"'), is_not("\""), char('"'))(input).map(
            |input| { (input.0, StringLiteral { string: input.1.to_string() }.into())})
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct IntegerLiteral {
    integer: u64
}

impl Token for IntegerLiteral {
    fn parse(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Box<Self>> {
        digit1(input).map(
            |input| { 
                match input.1.parse::<u64>() {
                    Ok(x) => (input.0, IntegerLiteral { integer: x}.into()),
                    Err(_) => unimplemented!()
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? I tried changing the type of alt::<_>, but that didn't work

Comment: You want a `Box<dyn Token>`, not `impl Token`

Comment: @Jmb Then I'll get 
```
mismatched types
expected enum `Result<(&str, Box<(dyn lexer::Token + 'static)>), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>>`
   found enum `Result<(&str, Box<StringLiteral>), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>>`
```

Comment: @Typhaon: you just need to coerce the concrete `Box` to a trait object—see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a6c429d3331592c93574db1725141b2c).